# PHP Redirect and Include

Tags: php, redirect, include

I have a php file (login.php) that processes a mysql connection,

then redirects to a sort of member's page after successful login.

That works flawlessly.

**HOWEVER**, when I attempt to **include("login.php")** and use, say the **$username** variable, it shows me the html of the redirect, or in this case the output of **header("location:members.html")**;

This may not be a flaw, possibly a function of php, if so, should i maybe segregate the login.php file to two files, one that checks and one that redirects if successful?

thanks in advance

FILE INFO:
login.html

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Login</title>

</head>
<body>

<form action="login.php" method="post">

<table cellpadding=10>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username"></input></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></input></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();


$con = mysql_connect($host,$_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);

if(!$con)
{
    die("Could Not Connect!" . "\n" . "Reason: " . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    //header("Location:interact.html");
    echo "<script>window.location = 'http://localhost/interact.html'</script>";
}

?>
```

interact.html

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Nexus | Envoy</title>

</head>

<body>
<p><?php echo "WELCOME ". $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is member's page a html page?

Comment: yup, member's page is an html one. a very basic one, shall i post the output of the attempt to use an included variable?

Comment: you need to convert it into a php page as include is a php function. Also why do not you use sessions to store variable names?

Comment: uhm, i AM including a php file, i.e. login.php. ok quick summary of what happens,

login.html > login.php if successful > members.html > on members page i want to have a message saying welcome $username.

i have not used session variables, and maybe i should actually! thanks for the suggestion cartina, but i'm pretty sure i'm going to have to come back to this question at some stage, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: OK. You are including login.php in another php file which redirects to the HTML. Can you post the code in that file?

Comment: sure, just btw, i've tried using sessions, still not working... maybe i'm doing something wrong, anyway i will post the code above.

Comment: interact.html should be a php file to include<?php echo "WELCOME " $_SESSION['username'] ?> You need to start session at top of this page also.

Comment: Replace  echo "<script>window.location = 'http://localhost/interact.html'</script>"; with header("location:interact.php");

Comment: okay... um, two questions:

1. even though i start a session in login.php, do i have to do it with every page the user interacts with?

2. why can't i redirect to an html page? is it a requirement that the redirect page has to be a php one?

Comment: i think there is something wrong with my configuration because i copied the code directly off (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

and pasted it into my interact.html file and that didnt work, something is going wrong, whoever is concerned may mark this as closed! thanks cartina for all your help.

Comment: 1. You have to do it with every page the user interacts with unless to  set it in your header file etc. which is included in every page.        2. If you want to use php code in a file it needs to be a php file otherwise code will not run. However if you do not need to perform anything in php, the file need not be a php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should slice the html into header, content and footer. The content changes for each page and header and footer will remain same. Add session_start() and code to establish connection in the header file.

Just to give you a rough idea...

login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();


$con = mysql_connect($host,$_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);

if(!$con)
{
    die("Could Not Connect!" . "\n" . "Reason: " . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from users where username = '".$_POST['username']."' and
      password = '".$_POST['password']."' ");

    if(mysql_num_rows > 0) 
   {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    header("Location:interact.php");
   }
  else
  {
    echo "Invalid Username/password";
   }
}

?>
```

Login

Username:




Password:

Interact.php

Nexus | Envoy

->Slice the html and include header and footer file.                                           ->Change the content in accordance with the url requested e.g. keep one file say index.php and include header then its content and lastly footer.                                    ->say the request is index.php?content=register,then you will get the values of $_REQUEST['content'] and based on it you will include the content file                              ->like if $_REQUEST['content'] = 'register', include('register.php'). Register.php will contain the content only and no header and footer.                                                      
->If  $_REQUEST['content'] is empty , show home page. 

Sample header.php:


    
    

    
    

    
    

Sample footer.php

    
    


Sample index.php

Comment: thanks cartina! :) i'm extremely new to php and some of the things are pretty strange coming from a java background, thanks to your help i eventually sorted it out! the fact that i gotta state session_start() on every page that i want to use the session variables is strange but never the less, syntax must be followed! :) you're a life saver!

Comment: @CraigWayne Please check the code above. It will help you to slice the template and do coding in standardized manner.

Comment: aha, checked it out, the silly mistake making interact.html insted of php was my downfall, i didnt actually know that i could include html code in a php file. now i know :) i miss java lol

Comment: @CraigWayne Sorry I had some problem editing the answer. Please check the new answer I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

1.Slice the html and include header and footer file.
2.Change the content in accordance with the url requested e.g. keep one file say index.php and include header then its content and lastly footer.                                    -say the request is index.php?content=register,then you will get the values of $_REQUEST['content'] and based on it you will include the content file                              ->like if $_REQUEST['content'] = 'register', include('register.php'). Register.php will contain the content only and no header and footer.
3.If  $_REQUEST['content'] is empty , show home page.

Sample header.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$con = mysql_connect($host,$_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);

if(!$con)
{
    die("Could Not Connect!" . "\n" . "Reason: " . mysql_error());
}

if($_REQUEST['content'] == 'register')  $title="Register";
if($_REQUEST['content'] == 'login')  $title="Login";
..
?>
<html>

<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?</title>

</head>
<body>
```

Sample footer.php

```
</body>
</html>
```

Sample index.php

```
<?php

require('header.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['content']) && !empty($_REQUEST['content']))
{
  if($_REQUEST['content'] == 'register')  include('register.php');
  if($_REQUEST['content'] == 'interact')  include('interact.php');
   if($_REQUEST['content'] == 'login')  include('login.php');
   ..
}
else
{
include('home.php');
}

require('footer.php');

?>
```

Sample content file (login.php)

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from users where username = '".$_POST['username']."' and
      password = '".$_POST['password']."' ");

if(mysql_num_rows > 0) 


  {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    header("Location:interact.php");
   }
  else
  {
    echo "Invalid Username/password";
   }

} ?>
<form action="login.php" method="post">

<table cellpadding=10>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username"></input></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></input></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```